# Taking Count of ScrollElasticsearchHttp processor in Nifi

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I am trying to take count from  ScrollElasticsearchHttp processor from ScrollElasticsearchHttp I am getting below data in queue.

```
    {"header": {"messageId": "111.26.121.15_ccc6", "businessId": "222"}, "security": {"securityUniqueIdentifier": "333", "businessDate": "2022-03-07", "securityIdentifier": [{"sourceCode": "ccccc", "cusipIdentifier": "ddddd"}, {"sourceCode": "dfdfd", "cusipIdentifier": "dddd"} ], "sourceSecurityClassification": [{"sourceCode": "dddd", "securityClassificationCode": "ObjectType"}, {"sourceCode": "dddd", "securityClassificationCode": "ddddd Classification"}, {"sourceCode": "fffff", "securityClassificationCode": "sssss"], "sourceSecurityIndustryClassification": [{"sourceCode": "ss", "securityIndustryClassificationCode": null } ], "agencyRating": null, "securityParty": null, "fixedIncome": {"issueDate": "2016-02-09", "closingPrice": null, "tradableLoan": {"loanTypeCode": null }, "exchangeCountryCode": null "floatingRateNote": null, "convertibleBond": null } 
}, 

{
"header": {"messageId": "111.26.121.15_49_ddd", "businessId": "222"}, "security": {"securityUniqueIdentifier": "333", "businessDate": "2022-03-07", "securityIdentifier": [{"sourceCode": "dddddd", "cusipIdentifier": "ffffff"}, {"sourceCode": "mmi-tor", "cusipIdentifier": "ffffff"} ], "sourceSecurityClassification": [{"sourceCode": "fffff", "securityClassificationCode": "ObjectType"}, {"sourceCode": "dddd", "securityClassificationCode": "ddddd Classification"}, {"sourceCode": "mmi-tor", "securityClassificationCode": "MMI Instrument"} ], "sourceSecurityIndustryClassification": [{"sourceCode": "ddddd", "securityIndustryClassificationCode": null } ], "agencyRating": null, "securityParty": null, "fixedIncome": {"issueDate": "2021-05-14", "closingPrice": null, "tradableLoan": {"loanTypeCode": null }, "exchangeCountryCode": null, "fixedIncomeSchedule": [{"scheduleTypeCode": "Principal"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Interest"} ], "callSchedule": [{"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"}, {"scheduleTypeCode": "Call Schedule"} ], "putSchedule": null, "ftseDetail": null }, "floatingRateNote": null } 
},
```

here I am expecting Count as 2 but evertime I am getting record.count as 1 can someone kindly suggest me what is the issue here.
to take count I am following below process.

```
using  EvaluateJsonPath processor:

Destination: flowfile-content
Return Type: auto-detect
header: $.header
```

Then using a QueryRecord processor:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)  FROM FLOWFILE;
```

Comment: Do you have 2 flowfiles in queue?

Comment: no Its creating only one.

Comment: Could you format data to valid JSON? I expect output from `ScrollElasticsearchHttp` processor with the field `hits` ( doc: "Each page of results is returned, wrapped in a JSON object like so: { "hits" : [ , , ] }." )